# How to redirect to an external URL in Angular2?

Tags: redirect, angular, angular2-routing

What is the method for redirecting the user to a completely external URL in Angular 2.  For example, if I need to redirect the user to an OAuth2 server in order to authenticate, how would I do that?

`Location.go()`, `Router.navigate()`, and `Router.navigateByUrl()` are fine for sending the user to another section (route) within the Angular 2 app, but I can't see how they could be used to redirect to an external site?

Comment: Note: If your external URL doesn't contain http:// or https://, Angular 4 will treat the URL as an internal route. In case anyone else is struggling with that.

Comment: Wow this thread is hilarious. Imagine explaining the benefits of Angular and then explaining navigating to an external URL. Estimated effort = 1 hour

Answer (score 347, accepted):

You can use this-> `window.location.href = '...';`

This would change the page to whatever you want..

Comment: Ugh, I tried calling it as a function for some reason rather than just changing the value.  Setting the value directly works.

Comment: Just remember that directly referencing the window will limit your code to  platforms with a window object.

Comment: @ender isn't there an alternative to it? There might be scenarios where we genuinely want to redirect to external links. Sure, we can use window.location.href, but like you say, it has its disadvantages. If there is a supported API in Angular, that would help better.

Comment: Sure, but that is 99% of all platforms that run javascript and need to do a page redirect. Even phantom/casperJs respect the window object. You can call `document.location.href` or even `Location.href` as they all refer to the same object. [Location Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

Comment: @DennisSmolek But if you try to compile this into an android app using Universal, wouldn't this behavior fail?

Comment: @ender what do you mean "Universal?" NativeScript doesn't have *window* that's true, but it also wouldn't be used to 'redirect' anything like the OP asked. You'd call a webview or an external app if you wanted a site and you'd use the router for internal pages. Windows Universal Platform (UWP) respects window, so does Ionic & Cordova.

Comment: @DennisSmolek, I believe ender means [angular universal](https://github.com/angular/universal), server side rendering. Is there a "safe" way to navigate to external URL in angular?

Comment: Not trying to be rude, I'm trying to understand, so to be clear @WilliamLohan, you're saying in the Angular Universal app for server side rendering that you want the angular compiler to render all the native pages and views, then also render a different website altogether? I don't think that's ever a situation the server-side would handle either. Serverside rendering still produces HTML, and your user would still use a browser to consume it so a basic link or `location.href`would still likely be the way to go...

Comment: @DennisSmolek you are right that would be a bad design, but I've always been under the impression that in general  it is bad practice to use the window object in angular because if it is possible for that code to run while server side rendering you'd get an undefined. So you'd think they'd have a solution.

Comment: any way using `routerLink` ?

Comment: `Binding to event property 'onclick' is disallowed for security reasons, please use (click)=...`

Comment: @DennisSmolek can you help me to solve this question? If i developed login in Angular6 and after login if user have admin permissions he should redirect to Laravel (5.5) backend. then angular frontend and laravel backend should know who is logged now.can u help me to solve this.

Comment: @DennisSmolek wouldn't it make testing of method with `window` reference more difficult?

Comment: @Eugene correct, without the usage of any dependency, it's really hard to do. A better solution is proposed by Brian (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42452665/2158015) such that you can provide a mock object instead of the actual document.

Comment: I tried to use this as a relative URL using a proxy but didn't work for me. Later, I had to use the original IP.

Answer (score 223):

An Angular approach to the methods previously described is to import `DOCUMENT` from `@angular/common` (or `@angular/platform-browser` in Angular
< 4) and use

```ts
document.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
```

inside a function.

**some-page.component.ts**

```ts
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
...
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

goToUrl(): void {
    this.document.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
}
```

**some-page.component.html**

```html
<button type="button" (click)="goToUrl()">Click me!</button>
```

Check out the [platformBrowser](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/platform-browser) repo for more info.

Comment: Would the target site know that the request is coming from our app, since the requirement here is to redirect for login purpose and hence the SSO app should redirect back to our app after success

Comment: In angular 4, DOCUMENT should be imported from `@angular/common` (i.e. `import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';`), but otherwise this works great! See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_tokens.ts

Comment: what is the purpose of injecting document this way `@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any`

Comment: @SunilGarg Injecting `DOCUMENT` makes it easier to replace the document object with a mock in unit tests. It also allows for an alternative implementation to be used on other platforms (server/mobile).

Comment: This works great with SSR(ng universal) as well. Thanks!

Comment: how do I redirect with params? e.g. pass `{ company : "test" }` to another url which is angular app

Comment: For strict typing I use, `constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }`

Comment: I am getting the error: ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Document -> Document -> Document]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Document!

Answer (score 45):

[The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34340883/1480995), as Dennis Smolek said, is dead simple.  Set `window.location.href` to the URL you want to switch to and it just works.

For example, if you had this method in your component's class file (controller):

```ts
goCNN() {
    window.location.href='http://www.cnn.com/';
}
```

Then you could call it quite simply with the appropriate `(click)` call on a button (or whatever) in your template:

```ts
<button (click)="goCNN()">Go to CNN</button>
```

Answer (score 34):

**I think you need à target="_blank"**, so then you can use `window.open` :

```
gotoGoogle() : void {
     window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank");
}
```

Answer (score 17):

If you've been using the OnDestry lifecycle hook, you might be interested in using something like this before calling window.location.href=...

```
    this.router.ngOnDestroy();
    window.location.href = 'http://www.cnn.com/';
```

that will trigger the OnDestry callback in your component that you might like.

Ohh, and also:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

is where you find the router.

---EDIT---
Sadly, I might have been wrong in the example above. At least it's not working as exepected in my production code right now - so, until I have time to investigate further, I solve it like this (since my app really need the hook when possible)

```
this.router.navigate(["/"]).then(result=>{window.location.href = 'http://www.cnn.com/';});
```

Basically routing to any (dummy) route to force the hook, and then navigate as requested.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. I was searching for some time for a solution and managed only to open an external link on a new tab, but on same tab all the window.open, location.pathname/href.... didn't let me to navigate away from my site.
This is the most clean and correct way to handle routing out of the angular app!

Answer (score 13):

in newer versions of Angular with window as an `any`

```
(window as any).open(someUrl, "_blank");
```

Comment: the best answer

Comment: Do newer versions on Angular not allow just plain window?

Answer (score 8):

****There are 2 options:****

1. if you want to redirect in same window/tab

   ```
    gotoExternalDomain(){
        window.location.href='http://google.com/'
    }
   ```
2. if you want to redirect in new tab

   ```
    gotoExternalDomain(){
        (window as any).open("http://google.com/", "_blank");
    }
   ```

Comment: Hi! Can you explain what's `"_blank"` for since link is opened in new tab without it as well?

Comment: @tz0 It opens an URL in a new tab.

Comment: @Coti but it opened that url without "_blank" as well

Comment: In other browsers the "_blank" can be required. But for example the latest chrome does not require this specification but other browsers would define it as "_self" -> you would redirect to the same tab.

Answer (score 5):

I did it using Angular 2 Location since I didn't want to manipulate the global window object myself.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html#!#prepareExternalUrl-anchor

It can be done like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
@Component({selector: 'app-component'})
class AppCmp {
  constructor(location: Location) {
    location.go('/foo');
  }
}
```

Comment: For me, this just changes the URL and the app state doesn't change (actual route looks the same). Even 'location.replaceState('/') did not act as I expected. `router.navigate(['/']);` is what did it for me.

Comment: Angular 2 Location doesn't sound applicable. The docs state that the purpose of location is: "Location is responsible for normalizing the URL against the application's base href." Using this to redirect to a URL within the application may be appropriate; using it to redirect to an external URL doesn't seem to fit with docs.

Answer (score 5):

I used `window.location.href='http://external-url';`

For me the the redirects **worked in Chrome, but didn't work in Firefox**.
The following code resolved my problem:

```
window.location.assign('http://external-url');
```

Answer (score 5):

After ripping my head off, the solution is just to add http:// to href.

```
<a href="http://www.URL.com">Go somewhere</a>
```

Comment: What question do you answer with that?

Comment: @GuidoFlohr I have a form where people have to put a link, and sometimes they put 'www.someLink.com' , and in this case the redirection is broken, due to the missing 'http' before. So this answer is correct.

Comment: @Nitneq The question is about redirecting in angular. And the answer has zero to do with the question.

Comment: @GuidoFlohr sometimes, Angular is not the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can redirect with multiple ways:

**like**

```
window.location.href = 'redirect_url';
```

**another way Angular document:**

import document from angular and the document must be inject as well as bellow  otherwise you will get error

```
import { DOCUMENT  } from '@angular/common';
export class AppComponent {
     constructor(
       @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
    ) {}
   this.document.location.href = 'redirect_url';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the above solutions worked for me, I just added

```
window.location.href = "www.google.com"
event.preventDefault();
```

This worked for me.

Or try using

```
window.location.replace("www.google.com");
```

Comment: Did you try doing window.open(url, "_self") ?
I think that you had a problem with overwriting your current URL because of used modules.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the current replies are optimal, but for cleaner code I would recomend the use of window instead of an injected reference of document as it is nothing less than a duplicate reference of the window itself. Only case where it better to use is when you cannot directly use the window.

```
const url : string = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338440/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-in-angular2" 
window.open(url, "_blank")
//window.open(url, "_self")
//window.open(url, "_parent")
//window.open(url, "_top")
```

This code will open a window whose second parameter which is the [target atribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attributes) that will decide where the URL will be opened.

The specific target atribute values are these: (mozilla)

> _self: the current browsing context. (Default)
>
> _blank: usually a new tab, but users can configure browsers to open a new window instead.
>
> _parent: the parent browsing context of the current one. If no parent, behaves as _self.
>
> _top: the topmost browsing context (the "highest" context that's an ancestor of the current one). If no ancestors, behaves as _self.

With this you can have a bit cleaner solution on where the new URL should be opened for the best experience of the end user

In any case you can replace router.navigate with

```
window.open("relativePathFromCurentURL","_self")
```

to navigate through your website. I can only recomend you this usage for cases where you do not want to import routing to some components.

Answer (score 0):

**To use @Inject, you must import it. I didn't see this in any of the answers.**

TS file:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-comp.page',
  templateUrl: './my-comp.page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-comp.page.component.scss']
})
export class MyCompPageComponent {

  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
  ) { }

  goToUrl(): void {
    this.document.location.href = 'https://google.com/';
  }

}
```

HTML file:

```
<button type="button" (click)="goToUrl()">Google</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your **component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  ...
  goToSpecificUrl(url): void {
    window.location.href=url;
  }

  gotoGoogle() : void {
    window.location.href='https://www.google.com';
  }
}
```

In your **component.html**

```
<button type="button" (click)="goToSpecificUrl('http://stackoverflow.com/')">Open URL</button>
<button type="button" (click)="gotoGoogle()">Open Google</button>

<li *ngFor="item of itemList" (click)="goToSpecificUrl(item.link)"> // (click) don't enable pointer when we hover so we should enable it by using css like: **cursor: pointer;**
```