# Angular 2 click on <a> does not go to link

Tags: angular

In a component I have something like this:

```
<a class="btn" [attr.href]="movie.imdbUrl" target="_blank" >IMDb</a>
```

but when I click on it nothing happens.

`movie.imdbUrl` points to "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2305051/" and I thought it would be equivalent to:

```
<a class="btn" href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2305051/" target="_blank" >IMDb</a>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most elegant way, but definitelly should work:

[How to redirect to an external URL in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338440/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-in-angular2)

```
window.location.href = '...';
```

Comment: My question is related to Angular 2. There is no more ng-href in Angular 2.

Comment: Im sorry, thought its angular 1, I've deleted the old post

Answer (score 1):

Thix example work for me :

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     template: `
        <a class="btn" [attr.href]="movie.imdbUrl" target="_blank" >IMDb</a>
        `
})
export class AppComponent {
    movie = {
       imdbUrl: "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2305051/"
    }
}
```

Are you sure you have defined the movie object correctly in your Component ?

Comment: I did but I also had a typo in an id attribute which read "movie" as well. That confused Angular. Can't say I blame it. Thanks to everybody who responded.