# How to navigate to complete different application in angular 5 using router

Tags: javascript, routes, angular5

I am having an angular 5 application running on localhost:3000 and on click of logout I need to route back to completely different application on another port. I am using

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('localhost:3000/home');
```

But what it does, its not going to new URL. In fact its appending that URL to my current route i.e.localhost:3001/home/localhost:3000/home

How can I just navigate to different app localhost:3000/home

This is what I have given on logout button click

```
 this.router.navigateByUrl('localhost:3000/home');
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338440/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-in-angular2

Comment: Why you need to use router.navigateByUrl ? You can do it another way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to an external URL in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338440/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-in-angular2)

Comment: and note that *"localhost:3000"* without preceding `//` is a relative path

Comment: No it didnt worked.Its not routing

Comment: window.location.href = 'localhost:3000/home';

Tried this but didnt work