# How can I create a link or route in angular 6 to a external url?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-router

I try to create a link from my angular 6 application to a external url. But my routing module converts al the links to internal pages.

Comment: Check out  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34340883/7812112) to route to external URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simply window.location.href = '...';