# Angular (6) view button (click) function redirect to Laravel(5.5) Back-end View

Tags: angular, laravel, redirect, angular6, backend

I want when i click angular front end button redirect to Laravel Backend View.I am new to angular.This is what i try to do.Please help me.

**frontend.component.html**

`<button type="button" (click)="userDetailsEdit()">Edit Details</button>`

**frontend.component.ts**

```
   userDetailsEdit() {
    alert('Its Working');
    this.authService.goToBreweryBarBackend();
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
 goToBreweryBarBackend() {
              const accessToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
              headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
              this.http.get(this.url.LaravelURL + 'api/goToBreweryBarBackend', { headers: new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken }) });
```

**api.php**

```
Route::get('/goToBreweryBarBackend', ['uses' => 'Homecontroller@index']);
```

**HomeController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}
```

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: no.there are no errors

Comment: What do you mean by "redirect"? In your code, you are trying to return a rendered HTML to the API request. Is this what you are trying to do? Or do you want a complete redirection to the Laravel side of the application?

Comment: @HarunYılmaz i already developed backend using Laravel 5.5. i want to go From angular (Frontend) to Laravel backend.

Comment: I mean, do you want only to get data (JSON, XML etc) from backend? Or do you want the users to redirect completely from Angular to Laravel?

Comment: @HarunYılmaz i can get data from backend.But i dont know how to redirect completely from angular to laravel.

Comment: I think this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338440/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-in-angular2

Comment: @HarunYılmaz ill try using this example.thank you.

Comment: @HarunYılmaz its work. but there is a problem.I developed user login in frontend. If frontend login i logged in one user and i try to goto backend, laravel doesnt know this user already logged in frontend or not.what should i do?

Comment: Laravel uses "session" guard as default for web. Maybe you can implement a middleware that gets the access token from URL and manually authenticate the user. So when you redirect your user, you can pass access token with the first redirection.

Comment: @HarunYılmaz Ill try as u said. Thank you so much your guidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
userDetailsEdit() {
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8000/intro'; 
}
```