# How to redirect external website URL in Anglar 11?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I have tried to open  redirect external website when button click in Angular , but its not working , Please help

```
<button  [routerLink]="www.google.com" >
   Goto google
  </button>
```

Comment: Please refer given answer on : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42452665/8717964

Answer (score 0):

You can use anchor tag for the same, using `target` as `_blank` will cause this to open in a new tab. Remove it if you need to redirect to the same tab.

```
 <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Go to Google</a>
```

If you want to use button, try below:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='https://google.com';" value="Go to Google" />
```

Comment: How can i redirect in button

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Goto google</a>
```

This will redirect the user to Google website

`[routerLink]` is for internal URL (within your Angular App)

Comment: possible to set a link button its self?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your question. Do you want to use button tag instead of anchor tag?

Comment: Yes, I want use button tag instead of anchor tag

Comment: In that case define a click event and within your click event use `window.location = "https://www.google.com"`. This will redirect your page to Google.